# No laravel, qual é o arquivo indicado para usar as MacroTraits?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

No Laravel, algumas classes usam o `trait` `MacroableTrait`.

Através desse trait é possível criar definições como:

```
HTML::macro('urlQuery', function ()
{
     // Faça alguma coisa aqui
});

HTML::urlQuery(); // O método urlQuery é "criado" magicamente
```

Porém, quero fazer tal definição de maneira global.

Em qual aquivo do Laravel eu poderia fazer tais definições (mantendo o máximo possível a organização do código)?

`bootstrap/start.php` ?

`app/start/global.php` ?

Ou outro arquivo ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em `bootstrap/start.php` acho uma má ideia, esse arquivo é utilizado para carregar o `autoload` e iniciar as classes do Laravel em si.

No `app/start/global.php` também funcionaria, porém você perderia um pouco da organização. (Vale lembrar que o `app/start/global.php` não existe mais no Laravel 5).

Eu criaria um arquivo separado dentro da minha pasta `app`, algo como `macros.php` e carregaria ele pelo composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    "files": [
        "app/macros.php"
    ]
},
```

Outra forma seria definir um *Service Provider* para criar todas essas macros. A [própria documentação](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/providers) coloca um exemplo envolvendo o método `macro` no método `boot` de um *Service Provider*:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory;

public function boot(ResponseFactory $factory)
{
    $factory->macro('caps', function ($value) {
        //
    });
}
```

Essas são algumas sugestões. Existem vários lugares que isso pode ser feito e o Laravel permite uma arquitetura flexível para sua aplicação. Assim escolha o que você que faz mais sentido para seu projeto.

Comment: Gratificação só poderá ser concedida em 22 horas :\

Comment: Ou ainda, poderia fazer `app/macros/request.php`, `app/macros/html.php` e assim por diante :)